# Apache Downloading a lot data, how to find out which script?

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd

Apache Downloading a lot data, how to find out which script?

I host a few sites, i noticed a ton of bandwidth being Downloading (not so much when uploading) when the httpd service is running, when I stop it, so does the heavy download use.

and I tried the netstat 80 grep command only to get a endless list of connections.

How could I find out what script (lets say a php) is downloading all this data?

Running
Centos
httpd

Answer (score 1):

You can check file opened by apache with `lsof` command.
i.e. `sudo lsof -c apache2 -nP -i :80` will do this and also prints out processes using port number 80(http).